GLMER and robust VCE in R
I am trying to replicate this command from Stata in R:
melogit pri_out_sanitation_coverage ib2.g1_name_of_ta##i.baseline_endline || village:, eform vce(robust)

I have used this code that produces very similar results but is nowhere near as neat or quick:
    model <- glmer(pri_out_sanitation_coverage ~ g1_name_of_ta * baseline_endline + (1| village), 
              family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
              data = df_hh2) 

# Calculate the bread matrix
bread_matrix <- bread(model, full = TRUE, ranpar = "var")

# Calculate the meat matrix at level 2 (random effects)
meat_matrix <- meat(model, level = 2)

# Use the sandwich function to compute the robust variance-covariance matrix
robust_vcov <- sandwich::sandwich(model, bread. = bread_matrix, meat. = meat_matrix)

# Extract fixed-effect coefficients
coef_estimates <- fixef(model)

# Extract the robust standard errors for fixed effects only
# Ensure that the dimension matches the fixed effects
robust_se <- sqrt(diag(robust_vcov)[1:length(coef_estimates)])

# Calculate odds ratios and robust confidence intervals
odds_ratios <- exp(coef_estimates)
ci_lower <- exp(coef_estimates - 1.96 * robust_se)
ci_upper <- exp(coef_estimates + 1.96 * robust_se)

# Calculate robust p-values using Wald test (z = beta / SE)
z_values <- coef_estimates / robust_se
p_values <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(z_values)))

# Create a summary table with odds ratios, CIs, and p-values
results <- data.frame(
  Estimate = coef_estimates,
  OR = odds_ratios,
  `Robust SE` = robust_se,
  `CI Lower` = ci_lower,
  `CI Upper` = ci_upper,
  `p-value` = p_values
)

I am sure there is a tidier way to create this output, but I am not sure how.
Example data that could be used:
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100,
  VillageID = rep(1:30, each = 10),
  TreatmentArm = rep(c("Control", "CLTS", "CLTS+"), each = 33, length.out = 100),
  Round = rep(c("Baseline", "Endline"), each = 50),
  OutcomeBinary = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3),
  OutcomeContinuous = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),
  TASpecificMedian = rep(c("Above", "Below"), each = 50),
  VillageSize = rep(c("Above", "Below"), each = 50)
)


Doesn't seem that bad to me. Wrap it in a function and call it a day? broom.mixed::tidy.merMod could presumably add a "robust" option but it doesn't exist at the moment ...
